# During big bang, everything expands same rate, homogenous, isotropic, nothing pulled towards each other. Did quantum randomness form stars, galaxies?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, big-bang, cosmological-inflation

During big bang, space expands separating everything at the same rate, homogenous and isotropic, nothing is pulled towards each others. Did quantum randomness form stars and galaxies? If there is no randomness, nothing would have happened, isn't it?

Comment: Hi Kenneth, I believe you are essentially correct, you can read more about structure formation in the early universe here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_formation

Comment: Yes, the quantum fluctuations in the early universe stretched to astronomical scale are responsible for the density fluctuations (galaxy clusters) observed today.

Comment: One interesting note is that quantum randomness already forms/supports stars anyways. Stellar core temperatures in sun-like stars are not hot enough to fuse anyways - the only way that fusion can occur to withstand gravitational self-force is by quantum tunneling.